# Calico node return nothing for command "/bin/calico-node -felix-ready"

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I'm a beginner developer of k8s system.
I want to check the readiness of calico node, so I sent a command to the node like below.

`$kubectl exec calico-node-d4tzk -n kube-system -- /bin/calico-node -felix-ready`

But nothing returns. I checked the logs of the node but there is no logs about the command too.
I wonder returning nothing means that felix is ready.

Comment: Could you share some details regarding how did you setup your cluster and the calico node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for myself, but I'm not sure whether it is correct or not.
In [projectcaclico/node/cmd/calico-node/main.go Line 98](https://github.com/projectcalico/node/blob/master/cmd/calico-node/main.go#L98), there are commands about checking liveness and readiness.

```
if *felixLive || *birdReady || *bird6Ready || *felixReady || *birdLive || *bird6Live {
        health.Run(*birdReady, *bird6Ready, *felixReady, *felixLive, *birdLive, *bird6Live, *thresholdTime)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
```

and then I looked into Run() function. In there, I found [code about felixReady](https://github.com/projectcalico/node/blob/d9e0793215f68d755b08224dbc3a68d7b8cdd9b2/pkg/health/health.go#L94).

```
    if felixReady {
        g.Go(func() error {
            if err := checkFelixHealth(ctx, felixReadinessEp, "readiness"); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("calico/node is not ready: felix is not ready: %+v", err)
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
```

As you can see, it returns nil when there is no problem. That's why I think that no returning means felix is ready.